# event receiver item delete

Tags: development

I have 2 lists as follows:

List A has items grouped by 'category' and a column 'time'

List B has the total time sumed up for each category, based on items of List A.

The functioning is this: when an item is added or edited in list A, an iterator goes thru the list and sums up the time columns of those item that belong to the same class. After this sum, List B Total Column is updated with the new value.

I can't get to work this when an item is deleted/deleting.
the best I can do is to use ItemDeleting, but only when I delete via the context menu. If I open the item and choose delete from the ribbon, sharepoint hangs and then times out.

This it the method I use

```
    public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemDeleting(properties);

        try
        {
            //using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
            {
                //gets the category
                String contrato = properties.ListItem["Contrato"].ToString();
                int minutosDescontar = Convert.ToInt32(properties.ListItem["Minutos"].ToString());
                int contratoID = calculaContratoID(contrato);

                //calls method to iterate and count values from items that belong to category
                int minutosGastosContrato = contabilizaAssistenciasContrato(contratoID, minutosDescontar);

                //updates listB with calculated totaltime
                atualizaMinutosContrato(contratoID, minutosGastosContrato);
            }
        }         
        catch { Exception e; }

    }
```

If i use ItemDeleted i lose the values, and although both deletion actions work, the total sum is not made correctly.

Any help, hint would be appreciated, thanks
David

Comment: on the deleted event you loose the values on properties, but you should get them in to beforeProperties.

Comment: *"If I open the item and choose delete from the ribbon, sharepoint hangs and then times out."* What do you mean here? ItemDeleting doesn't work for you when you are using forms? That's strange I would say.

Comment: are you tried to debug it ? may be the issue at contabilizaAssistenciasContrato ,  atualizaMinutosContrato should you also update your answer with this functions ?

Comment: the functions are ok, although the deleted vs deleting causes some issues. I thought i could pass my values to static variables upon the deleting action, and then get them back on the deleted method. I can populate the values, but the deleted method is not doing what is supposed to.

Comment: itemdeleting{ base.itemdeleting(properties); var1=X; var2=Y; } <- works

Comment: itemdeleted {callmethod(X,Y); baseItemdeleted(propertie)}; <- doesn't work, I'm unable to call this method when an item is deleted...